# How to handle an late text in playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to wait until text appears on certain element. My page is fully loaded but on one screen there is something like a "buffering", informations on the element appears later, I don't want to use page.waitForTimeout because it is "luck" depending, what if my timeout is too small etc. I want to wait for text to appear

My current state is

```
await expect(page.locator('my-locator')).toContainText('a')
```

It is working pretty well because letter "a" is in basically every single world and I want to find a solution to just wait for text to appears, nothing else, I just want my page to wait until that one element which is "buffering" shows fully, but I know there is a solution for it which I don't know about, looking for help!

Comment: Locators [auto wait](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability), so there's normally no action required. Waiting just works. Which element showing buffering? Select it using something specific, possibly using the [codegen](https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen). It's impossible to help without a page and a [mcve] of your code to work from. Thanks.

Comment: I got some buttons on the site about new invoices, archive ones etc. If the user log into the site, on the top of the app there is a "panel" which "downloading" if the logged user have an job started already, and that information about pending job is "buffering", loading over time, using selector it is hard to wait for it without .toContainText - at least I don't know the solution for that

Comment: @tomejto so you need to wait for the 'downloading' job to complete before you click the button?

Comment: Basically yes, because that panel shows me if there is a pending job or not and if there is a pending job I will finish it, if not the panel says there is no job started at the moment so I'm clicking into available jobs and starts it - that's why my test depends on that panel alone because I'm using that in my if function.

If im saying something like bullshit, I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced, I'm writing tests for 3 weeks in my first job ever in IT - so sorry if I'm missing something important or chatting shit

Comment: @tomejto its a bit tricky to give very precise answers without the HTML, but I left an answer with a few ways to approach this. Lemme know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to wait for the downloading/buffering panel to complete before you action you next click, so we can do this a few ways.

1. We can simply check when the buffering panel is done. This can be done in several ways but an easy one is something like:

   ```
   const bufferingElement = page.locator('<your locator for buffering panel>');
   await expect(bufferingElement).toHaveCount(0);
   ```

   This will find the buffering element, whatever that is for your site, and then wait until it disappears, i.e. loading complete. You can easily extend that to look for specific text such as 'loading' or whatever you need. As I don't know your HTML, I am keeping it generic here, but the logic is the same.

   If you wanted to conditionally check for it, its very similar. Something like:

   ```
   const bufferingElement = page.locator('<your locator for buffering panel>');

   //If there is a buffering job, wait for it to complete
   if(await bufferingElement.count() > 0){
     //Do whatever you need to do while job is buffering
     await expect(bufferingElement).toHaveCount(0);
   }
   ```
2. If we know what the endpoint is that controls this buffering, we can wait until it is done, before moving on. Something like this could work for that:

   ```
   const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(response =>
     response.url() === '<endpoint url>' && response.status() === 200
   );
   await page.getByRole('<role>', { name: '<name>' }).click();
   const response = await responsePromise;
   ```

   This code block creates a promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), then you should replace the 'getByRole' line with the action that performs the load, which is presumably just opening the page under test. Then, we resolve the promise, at which point the response is returned and buffering complete, then you can move on.
3. If you want to use a more precise locator than getting text that contains 'a' I would recommend using the getByRole locator. This is the best way to go as it uses a user-centric way to gather your locators. Essentially you would find your elements role, and its name value, and use that. It is much nicer than using a text contains type of approach. This link explains a nice easy way to find those things - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/accessibility-chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `page.waitForFunction()` ([docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function)). It's great for nuanced criteria like this one.

```js
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  return document.querySelector('my-locator')?.innerText.includes('a');
}, {timeout: 1000 * 60 /* max millis before aborting */ });
```

Comment: But the thing is I don't want to use 'a'. I want the code to look professional, my boss is demanding and he doesn't like the 'a' in the code

Comment: If the element is truly empty before the update, use '.length' to detect the update.